# js restructure object to elevate property

Tags: javascript

I have the following array with objects:

```
[
   {
        "timestamp_start":{"S":"2016-11-28T10:35:48.100Z"},
        "timestamp_stop":{"S":"2016-11-28T10:39:48.100Z"},
        "deviceId":{"S":"0"},
        "userId":{"S":"0"}
   }
]
```

The S property indicates that the value is a string. I do not need this information later on and would like to drop it and rather 'elevate' the value one level to get the following array:

```
[
   {
        "timestamp_start": "2016-11-28T10:35:48.100Z",
        "timestamp_stop": "2016-11-28T10:39:48.100Z",
        "deviceId": "0",
        "userId": "0"
   }
]
```

I already tried some variations with Object .map .keys .values but failed to get a nice solution.

Comment: Can you share these variations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and update the object.

```js
var data = [{
  "timestamp_start": {
    "S": "2016-11-28T10:35:48.100Z"
  },
  "timestamp_stop": {
    "S": "2016-11-28T10:39:48.100Z"
  },
  "deviceId": {
    "S": "0"
  },
  "userId": {
    "S": "0"
  }
}];

data.forEach(function(obj) {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(k) {
    obj[k] = obj[k][Object.keys(obj[k])[0]]
  })
})

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map()` and `reduce()` to get desired result.

```js
var data = [{
  "timestamp_start": {
    "S": "2016-11-28T10:35:48.100Z"
  },
  "timestamp_stop": {
    "S": "2016-11-28T10:39:48.100Z"
  },
  "deviceId": {
    "S": "0"
  },
  "userId": {
    "S": "0"
  }
}]

var result = data.map(function(e) {
  return Object.keys(e).reduce(function(r, k) {
    r[k] = e[k].S
    return r;
  }, {})
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could look for property `S` and take the value.

```js
var object = { timestamp_start: { S: "2016-11-28T10:35:48.100Z" }, timestamp_stop: { S: "2016-11-28T10:39:48.100Z" }, deviceId: { S: "0" }, userId: {S: "0" } };
    
Object.keys(object).forEach(function (k) {
    if ('S' in object[k]) {
       object[k] = object[k].S;
    }
});

console.log(object);
```